# Pandas time series dataframe plot not in index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I've got a data frame whose first 5 elements look like this:

[image]

I have deleted all the null values from this dataframe. Here's the data types of each column:

[image]

Later, when I tried to get a plot by using

```
data.plot(x=data.timestamp, style='.-')
```

It shows up this error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-e11e322ec19a> in <module>
      4 
      5 # data.coffees.plot(x=data.timestamp, style='.-')
----> 6 data.plot(x=data.timestamp, style='.-')
      7 # import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      8 # plt.plot(x=data.timestamp, y=data.coffees, style=".-")

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2939                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2940                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2941                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2942     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2943 

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1975                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1976                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1977                  **kwds)
   1978 
   1979 

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1764                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
   1765                     x = data_cols[x]
-> 1766                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
   1767                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
   1768                 data = data.set_index(x)

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2680         if isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, Index, list)):
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):
   2684             return self._getitem_frame(key)

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_array(self, key)
   2724             return self._take(indexer, axis=0)
   2725         else:
-> 2726             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
   2727             return self._take(indexer, axis=1)
   2728 

~/Softwares-and-tools/Anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter)
   1325                 if mask.any():
   1326                     raise KeyError('{mask} not in index'
-> 1327                                    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
   1328 
   1329                 return com._values_from_object(indexer)

KeyError: "['2011-10-03T08:22:00.000000000' '2011-10-04T11:48:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-05T10:47:00.000000000' '2011-10-05T13:15:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-06T07:21:00.000000000' '2011-10-06T10:04:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-06T12:14:00.000000000' '2011-10-06T12:49:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-06T14:52:00.000000000' '2011-10-07T07:34:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-07T08:37:00.000000000' '2011-10-07T11:09:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-07T13:14:00.000000000' '2011-10-07T15:20:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-07T16:50:00.000000000' '2011-10-09T16:53:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-10T07:29:00.000000000' '2011-10-10T10:13:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-10T13:41:00.000000000' '2011-10-10T14:02:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-10T15:23:00.000000000' '2011-10-11T14:09:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-12T08:11:00.000000000' '2011-10-12T09:57:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-12T10:06:00.000000000' '2011-10-12T12:01:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-12T12:30:00.000000000' '2011-10-12T13:56:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-13T09:10:00.000000000' '2011-10-13T10:52:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-13T11:04:00.000000000' '2011-10-13T14:41:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-13T15:06:00.000000000' '2011-10-13T15:45:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-13T15:58:00.000000000' '2011-10-14T09:02:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-14T10:02:00.000000000' '2011-10-14T14:07:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-17T09:24:00.000000000' '2011-10-17T11:19:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-17T14:05:00.000000000' '2011-10-18T09:20:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-18T09:39:00.000000000' '2011-10-18T11:32:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-18T12:54:00.000000000' '2011-10-19T09:15:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-19T09:31:00.000000000' '2011-10-19T14:08:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-19T15:11:00.000000000' '2011-10-20T13:01:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-20T15:59:00.000000000' '2011-10-21T10:39:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-21T13:15:00.000000000' '2011-10-21T15:09:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-24T09:51:00.000000000' '2011-10-24T10:15:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-24T10:21:00.000000000' '2011-10-24T14:32:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-25T07:54:00.000000000' '2011-10-25T09:37:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-25T14:30:00.000000000' '2011-10-25T17:52:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-26T09:15:00.000000000' '2011-10-26T09:42:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-26T11:59:00.000000000' '2011-10-26T13:38:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-27T08:03:00.000000000' '2011-10-27T11:14:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-27T13:51:00.000000000' '2011-10-28T13:33:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-31T10:58:00.000000000' '2011-10-31T11:00:00.000000000'\n '2011-10-31T13:58:00.000000000' '2011-10-31T14:35:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-01T08:21:00.000000000' '2011-11-01T09:33:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-01T10:13:00.000000000' '2011-11-01T15:07:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-01T15:19:00.000000000' '2011-11-02T10:56:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-03T09:52:00.000000000' '2011-11-04T10:41:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-04T13:22:00.000000000' '2011-11-08T13:32:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-08T15:08:00.000000000' '2011-11-09T12:09:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-09T13:57:00.000000000' '2011-11-10T10:26:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-10T15:36:00.000000000' '2011-11-10T15:52:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-11T10:27:00.000000000' '2011-11-11T12:19:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-11T13:29:00.000000000' '2011-11-14T10:53:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-14T19:21:00.000000000' '2011-11-15T10:32:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-15T15:04:00.000000000' '2011-11-15T16:00:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-16T09:24:00.000000000' '2011-11-16T09:58:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-16T12:57:00.000000000' '2011-11-17T11:24:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-17T13:59:00.000000000' '2011-11-18T11:15:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-18T16:05:00.000000000' '2011-11-20T14:20:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-21T09:21:00.000000000' '2011-11-21T10:06:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-21T11:34:00.000000000' '2011-11-21T11:40:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-21T14:07:00.000000000' '2011-11-23T09:33:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-23T09:45:00.000000000' '2011-11-23T12:31:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-24T11:27:00.000000000' '2011-11-24T13:33:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-24T14:13:00.000000000' '2011-11-24T15:00:00.000000000'\n '2011-11-28T09:41:00.000000000' '2011-11-30T13:20:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-01T11:12:00.000000000' '2011-12-03T17:02:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-05T14:53:00.000000000' '2011-12-06T10:36:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-06T11:29:00.000000000' '2011-12-06T13:57:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-07T10:37:00.000000000' '2011-12-07T11:33:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-07T15:02:00.000000000' '2011-12-08T13:56:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-09T10:32:00.000000000' '2011-12-09T15:47:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-09T17:29:00.000000000' '2011-12-12T09:30:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-12T13:42:00.000000000' '2011-12-13T10:08:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-13T13:32:00.000000000' '2011-12-13T13:36:00.000000000'\n '2011-12-13T15:09:00.000000000' '2011-12-19T12:09:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-11T14:42:00.000000000' '2012-01-11T17:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-13T10:31:00.000000000' '2012-01-13T14:59:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-16T09:58:00.000000000' '2012-01-16T11:58:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-16T13:51:00.000000000' '2012-01-16T15:28:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-18T11:14:00.000000000' '2012-01-18T14:28:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-18T18:02:00.000000000' '2012-01-20T15:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-21T13:48:00.000000000' '2012-01-23T11:51:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-23T13:15:00.000000000' '2012-01-24T10:29:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-25T09:44:00.000000000' '2012-01-25T10:03:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-26T10:18:00.000000000' '2012-01-26T13:02:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-27T10:33:00.000000000' '2012-01-27T11:01:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-27T14:23:00.000000000' '2012-01-28T13:35:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-30T09:02:00.000000000' '2012-01-30T10:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-01-30T13:30:00.000000000' '2012-02-01T09:21:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-01T12:31:00.000000000' '2012-02-01T13:30:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-01T16:21:00.000000000' '2012-02-02T10:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-02T13:36:00.000000000' '2012-02-03T12:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-03T15:38:00.000000000' '2012-02-04T11:48:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-04T14:55:00.000000000' '2012-02-05T13:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-05T15:33:00.000000000' '2012-02-06T07:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-06T10:55:00.000000000' '2012-02-06T11:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-06T12:42:00.000000000' '2012-02-06T17:50:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-08T11:17:00.000000000' '2012-02-10T07:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-10T12:52:00.000000000' '2012-02-10T16:32:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-11T12:35:00.000000000' '2012-02-12T13:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-13T16:31:00.000000000' '2012-02-17T13:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-19T15:29:00.000000000' '2012-02-20T12:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-20T17:12:00.000000000' '2012-02-21T08:49:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-22T09:54:00.000000000' '2012-02-22T13:23:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-22T16:05:00.000000000' '2012-02-22T16:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-23T15:57:00.000000000' '2012-02-24T13:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-25T16:39:00.000000000' '2012-02-27T08:42:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-27T15:35:00.000000000' '2012-02-28T11:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-02-29T09:27:00.000000000' '2012-02-29T12:57:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-01T10:07:00.000000000' '2012-03-01T14:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-02T15:13:00.000000000' '2012-03-04T15:07:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-06T11:13:00.000000000' '2012-03-07T12:50:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-08T12:59:00.000000000' '2012-03-09T12:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-12T10:17:00.000000000' '2012-03-12T12:07:00.000000000'\n '2012-03-12T17:28:00.000000000' '2012-04-04T09:48:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-04T11:12:00.000000000' '2012-04-04T13:33:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-04T17:00:00.000000000' '2012-04-04T17:02:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-05T10:39:00.000000000' '2012-04-05T11:59:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-10T09:51:00.000000000' '2012-04-10T10:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-10T13:55:00.000000000' '2012-04-11T11:37:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-26T16:45:00.000000000' '2012-04-26T17:59:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-27T11:03:00.000000000' '2012-04-27T13:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-30T08:58:00.000000000' '2012-04-30T13:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-04-30T14:54:00.000000000' '2012-05-01T14:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-02T12:00:00.000000000' '2012-05-02T13:25:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-03T12:14:00.000000000' '2012-05-03T13:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-04T11:08:00.000000000' '2012-05-07T10:17:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-07T12:56:00.000000000' '2012-05-07T13:31:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-07T18:20:00.000000000' '2012-05-08T11:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-08T11:47:00.000000000' '2012-05-09T12:54:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-09T14:10:00.000000000' '2012-05-09T16:55:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-10T12:12:00.000000000' '2012-05-10T15:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-10T17:59:00.000000000' '2012-05-11T15:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-12T09:50:00.000000000' '2012-05-14T10:02:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-14T12:23:00.000000000' '2012-05-14T15:27:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-15T09:07:00.000000000' '2012-05-15T09:19:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-15T13:06:00.000000000' '2012-05-15T13:42:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-16T09:17:00.000000000' '2012-05-16T10:25:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-16T13:24:00.000000000' '2012-05-16T16:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-16T16:57:00.000000000' '2012-05-17T09:22:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-17T13:02:00.000000000' '2012-05-17T14:25:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-17T18:48:00.000000000' '2012-05-18T09:19:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-18T12:57:00.000000000' '2012-05-18T13:14:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-20T14:00:00.000000000' '2012-05-21T09:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-21T14:40:00.000000000' '2012-05-22T10:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-22T13:23:00.000000000' '2012-05-24T09:23:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-24T13:23:00.000000000' '2012-05-24T15:51:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-25T09:19:00.000000000' '2012-05-25T11:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-25T11:55:00.000000000' '2012-05-25T12:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-26T15:40:00.000000000' '2012-05-28T09:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-28T12:57:00.000000000' '2012-05-28T19:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-29T11:07:00.000000000' '2012-05-29T13:29:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-31T09:09:00.000000000' '2012-05-31T12:41:00.000000000'\n '2012-05-31T17:24:00.000000000' '2012-06-01T09:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-01T13:27:00.000000000' '2012-06-01T18:50:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-04T08:42:00.000000000' '2012-06-04T12:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-04T13:25:00.000000000' '2012-06-04T15:09:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-05T15:29:00.000000000' '2012-06-05T16:56:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-06T09:18:00.000000000' '2012-06-06T10:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-06T13:33:00.000000000' '2012-06-06T15:42:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-07T08:44:00.000000000' '2012-06-07T09:30:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-07T13:36:00.000000000' '2012-06-07T17:32:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-07T19:11:00.000000000' '2012-06-08T09:53:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-08T10:04:00.000000000' '2012-06-08T11:55:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-11T09:13:00.000000000' '2012-06-11T12:41:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-11T13:25:00.000000000' '2012-06-11T14:59:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-11T16:01:00.000000000' '2012-06-11T19:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-12T08:15:00.000000000' '2012-06-15T12:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-15T12:43:00.000000000' '2012-06-17T13:43:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-17T17:44:00.000000000' '2012-06-18T09:12:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-18T13:02:00.000000000' '2012-06-18T17:55:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-19T11:28:00.000000000' '2012-06-20T12:49:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-26T11:18:00.000000000' '2012-06-26T15:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-26T19:35:00.000000000' '2012-06-27T12:06:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-28T11:46:00.000000000' '2012-06-28T17:42:00.000000000'\n '2012-06-29T09:17:00.000000000' '2012-06-29T16:47:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-02T12:12:00.000000000' '2012-07-02T17:09:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-03T12:17:00.000000000' '2012-07-03T16:09:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-04T09:58:00.000000000' '2012-07-04T12:49:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-04T13:42:00.000000000' '2012-07-05T09:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-05T12:08:00.000000000' '2012-07-05T16:12:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-06T13:24:00.000000000' '2012-07-06T18:03:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-07T17:12:00.000000000' '2012-07-08T12:03:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-09T09:20:00.000000000' '2012-07-09T12:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-09T14:20:00.000000000' '2012-07-10T09:12:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-10T13:36:00.000000000' '2012-07-11T09:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-12T09:21:00.000000000' '2012-07-13T09:19:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-16T12:53:00.000000000' '2012-07-16T16:57:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-17T09:16:00.000000000' '2012-07-20T09:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-25T09:16:00.000000000' '2012-07-25T10:39:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-25T10:54:00.000000000' '2012-07-25T14:32:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-26T09:58:00.000000000' '2012-07-26T11:39:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-26T13:38:00.000000000' '2012-07-27T09:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-27T11:16:00.000000000' '2012-07-28T20:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-30T11:15:00.000000000' '2012-07-30T13:35:00.000000000'\n '2012-07-30T16:10:00.000000000' '2012-07-31T13:26:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-01T13:13:00.000000000' '2012-08-01T14:23:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-02T09:16:00.000000000' '2012-08-02T13:18:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-02T15:46:00.000000000' '2012-08-05T16:35:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-06T11:08:00.000000000' '2012-08-06T11:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-06T13:18:00.000000000' '2012-08-06T13:37:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-07T10:38:00.000000000' '2012-08-07T13:02:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-08T09:28:00.000000000' '2012-08-08T12:26:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-08T13:19:00.000000000' '2012-08-08T13:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-08T15:49:00.000000000' '2012-08-09T10:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-09T11:40:00.000000000' '2012-08-09T13:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-09T13:25:00.000000000' '2012-08-09T15:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-13T09:36:00.000000000' '2012-08-13T13:46:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-14T09:23:00.000000000' '2012-08-14T10:46:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-14T14:23:00.000000000' '2012-08-14T19:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-15T09:27:00.000000000' '2012-08-15T14:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-16T09:16:00.000000000' '2012-08-16T15:42:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-17T09:26:00.000000000' '2012-08-17T13:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-20T09:28:00.000000000' '2012-08-20T14:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-21T10:06:00.000000000' '2012-08-21T13:01:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-21T16:05:00.000000000' '2012-08-22T09:57:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-22T13:52:00.000000000' '2012-08-23T09:17:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-23T13:00:00.000000000' '2012-08-23T13:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-24T15:32:00.000000000' '2012-08-25T15:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-27T09:55:00.000000000' '2012-08-27T13:53:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-28T10:48:00.000000000' '2012-08-29T13:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-30T09:33:00.000000000' '2012-08-30T13:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-30T17:36:00.000000000' '2012-08-31T09:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-31T11:21:00.000000000' '2012-08-31T13:53:00.000000000'\n '2012-08-31T15:20:00.000000000' '2012-09-01T14:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-01T17:43:00.000000000' '2012-09-03T12:19:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-03T16:15:00.000000000' '2012-09-04T11:43:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-04T14:52:00.000000000' '2012-09-05T09:28:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-05T14:06:00.000000000' '2012-09-05T14:48:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-06T13:15:00.000000000' '2012-09-07T09:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-07T09:49:00.000000000' '2012-09-07T13:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-07T16:53:00.000000000' '2012-09-10T09:30:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-10T13:30:00.000000000' '2012-09-10T17:21:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-11T13:11:00.000000000' '2012-09-12T17:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-13T11:07:00.000000000' '2012-09-13T13:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-13T14:51:00.000000000' '2012-09-14T07:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-14T11:35:00.000000000' '2012-09-15T13:28:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-15T18:53:00.000000000' '2012-09-17T09:37:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-17T13:09:00.000000000' '2012-09-18T10:22:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-19T14:48:00.000000000' '2012-09-20T09:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-20T13:04:00.000000000' '2012-09-21T11:51:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-21T12:56:00.000000000' '2012-09-24T13:13:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-24T13:39:00.000000000' '2012-09-24T15:21:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-25T11:10:00.000000000' '2012-09-25T15:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-26T09:28:00.000000000' '2012-09-26T12:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-26T16:02:00.000000000' '2012-09-27T10:00:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-27T11:50:00.000000000' '2012-09-27T13:32:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-28T09:22:00.000000000' '2012-09-28T10:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-28T13:17:00.000000000' '2012-09-29T09:05:00.000000000'\n '2012-09-29T15:16:00.000000000' '2012-10-01T09:23:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-01T09:58:00.000000000' '2012-10-01T12:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-01T13:08:00.000000000' '2012-10-03T17:06:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-04T08:20:00.000000000' '2012-10-04T10:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-04T12:43:00.000000000' '2012-10-04T14:33:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-05T08:22:00.000000000' '2012-10-05T12:47:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-05T13:02:00.000000000' '2012-10-05T15:10:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-05T17:40:00.000000000' '2012-10-08T13:29:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-08T13:48:00.000000000' '2012-10-08T15:03:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-09T09:44:00.000000000' '2012-10-09T11:16:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-09T12:25:00.000000000' '2012-10-10T10:03:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-10T11:03:00.000000000' '2012-10-10T11:53:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-10T13:10:00.000000000' '2012-10-10T13:45:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-10T15:50:00.000000000' '2012-10-11T10:18:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-11T12:58:00.000000000' '2012-10-12T09:47:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-12T10:50:00.000000000' '2012-10-12T13:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-13T12:37:00.000000000' '2012-10-13T15:32:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-14T16:44:00.000000000' '2012-10-15T08:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-15T10:35:00.000000000' '2012-10-15T13:24:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-15T14:57:00.000000000' '2012-10-16T12:37:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-17T09:50:00.000000000' '2012-10-17T10:25:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-17T13:00:00.000000000' '2012-10-17T13:01:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-17T13:50:00.000000000' '2012-10-18T09:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-18T10:04:00.000000000' '2012-10-18T11:40:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-18T13:41:00.000000000' '2012-10-19T10:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-19T16:18:00.000000000' '2012-10-20T14:20:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-20T16:35:00.000000000' '2012-10-20T16:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-22T10:46:00.000000000' '2012-10-22T12:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-22T13:28:00.000000000' '2012-10-22T16:39:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-23T12:43:00.000000000' '2012-10-25T09:55:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-26T16:03:00.000000000' '2012-10-30T09:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-31T12:51:00.000000000' '2012-10-31T14:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-10-31T18:02:00.000000000' '2012-11-01T11:19:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-01T15:20:00.000000000' '2012-11-02T11:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-02T13:46:00.000000000' '2012-11-05T11:17:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-05T13:25:00.000000000' '2012-11-06T09:30:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-07T09:53:00.000000000' '2012-11-07T10:59:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-07T12:45:00.000000000' '2012-11-08T11:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-08T13:50:00.000000000' '2012-11-09T10:07:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-09T10:26:00.000000000' '2012-11-09T12:11:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-09T12:48:00.000000000' '2012-11-09T13:14:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-12T09:34:00.000000000' '2012-11-12T09:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-12T13:21:00.000000000' '2012-11-14T12:50:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-15T14:38:00.000000000' '2012-11-16T10:22:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-16T13:45:00.000000000' '2012-11-19T11:27:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-19T13:18:00.000000000' '2012-11-19T16:27:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-20T10:49:00.000000000' '2012-11-20T12:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-20T13:44:00.000000000' '2012-11-21T09:58:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-21T16:27:00.000000000' '2012-11-23T11:38:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-23T12:45:00.000000000' '2012-11-23T13:22:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-23T13:52:00.000000000' '2012-11-24T11:44:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-24T12:49:00.000000000' '2012-11-26T10:00:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-26T10:50:00.000000000' '2012-11-26T13:34:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-28T09:58:00.000000000' '2012-11-28T12:58:00.000000000'\n '2012-11-30T16:07:00.000000000' '2012-12-03T11:21:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-03T17:00:00.000000000' '2012-12-04T10:47:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-04T13:03:00.000000000' '2012-12-04T14:08:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-05T11:13:00.000000000' '2012-12-06T14:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-07T11:22:00.000000000' '2012-12-08T12:29:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-08T14:20:00.000000000' '2012-12-08T17:15:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-10T12:12:00.000000000' '2012-12-11T10:29:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-11T14:23:00.000000000' '2012-12-12T09:43:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-12T13:07:00.000000000' '2012-12-12T15:17:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-14T10:24:00.000000000' '2012-12-17T14:36:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-18T11:04:00.000000000' '2012-12-18T13:50:00.000000000'\n '2012-12-21T15:23:00.000000000' '2013-01-08T13:58:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-09T15:25:00.000000000' '2013-01-10T11:05:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-11T10:57:00.000000000' '2013-01-11T13:36:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-11T17:06:00.000000000' '2013-01-15T08:25:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-16T12:38:00.000000000' '2013-01-16T18:09:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-17T13:45:00.000000000' '2013-01-21T14:07:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-28T14:01:00.000000000' '2013-01-29T13:43:00.000000000'\n '2013-01-29T15:06:00.000000000' '2013-02-04T13:25:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-06T17:33:00.000000000' '2013-02-07T13:30:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-12T08:36:00.000000000' '2013-02-12T11:39:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-13T13:58:00.000000000' '2013-02-16T11:55:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-18T13:46:00.000000000' '2013-02-21T13:44:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-21T15:02:00.000000000' '2013-02-25T13:33:00.000000000'\n '2013-02-25T17:25:00.000000000' '2013-02-27T09:33:00.000000000'\n '2013-03-04T10:46:00.000000000' '2013-03-04T11:12:00.000000000'\n '2013-03-04T16:43:00.000000000' '2013-03-05T10:42:00.000000000'\n '2013-03-05T13:29:00.000000000' '2013-03-08T10:28:00.000000000'\n '2013-03-12T08:28:00.000000000' '2013-04-05T11:20:00.000000000'\n '2013-04-27T11:04:00.000000000' '2013-09-12T15:38:00.000000000'\n '2013-09-13T10:28:00.000000000'] not in index"
```

Plese help

Comment: Try `data = data.set_index('timestamp')`.

Comment: I think you meant to write `data.plot(x="timestamp", style='.-')`, but depending on the pandas version in use that may not result in the desired plot. Rather use the timestamp column as index,  `data.set_index("timestamp").plot(style=".-")`

Comment: @Kyle, I tried what you said and it showed this error: `KeyError: 'timestamp'`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I tried both of your suggestions, one after the other and they showed the same error: `KeyError: 'timestamp'`

Comment: `print(df.columns)` Is `timestamp` there? If not, you have changed your df from what you have shown in the question.

Comment: If you have executed @Kyle's suggestion, your data does now not contain any "timestamp" column any more, because it is now the index.

Comment: @Kyle and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I restarted my jupyter notebook, tried `data.set_index("timestamp").plot(style=".-")`, and it worked. Thank you guys for your help!